AWS lambda deployment sub folder issue
Trying to deploy some lambda functions with AWS CDK (latest version)

I keep getting this:
'Error: Lock file at ../src/auth/package-lock.json doesn't exist'
But when I console log from the Github action runner I get what seems to be a valid response...
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../src/auth')):
      /github/workspace/cdk/src/auth 

    console.log(fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../src/auth'))):
      [ 'index.ts', 'package-lock.json', 'package.json', 'tsconfig.json' ]

code...
    const lambdaAuthorizer = new cdk.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'AuthorizerLambda', {
      entry: path.join(__dirname, '../src/auth/index.ts'),
      handler: 'handler',
      runtime: cdk.aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST

})

...

 const lambdaLenovoService = new cdk.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'LenovoService', {
      entry: path.join(__dirname, '../src/lenovo/index.ts'),
      handler: 'handler',
      runtime: cdk.aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
    })

I have another repo that uses the exact same code/folder structure expect for that the index.ts is right in /src/ and not in a subfolder - I have 2 lambda functions that I need to deploy so I wanted folders
here is the error from github actions
Bundling asset CdkStack/AuthorizerLambda/Code/Stage...
esbuild cannot run locally. Switching to Docker bundling.
Error: R] Could not resolve "/asset-input/src/auth/index.ts"

1 error
/github/workspace/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2
`),localBundling=options.local?.tryBundle(bundleDir,options),!localBundling){const assetStagingOptions={sourcePath:this.sourcePath,bundleDir,...options};switch(options.bundlingFileAccess){case bundling_1().BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY:new(asset_staging_1()).AssetBundlingVolumeCopy(assetStagingOptions).run();break;case bundling_1().BundlingFileAccess.BIND_MOUNT:default:new(asset_staging_1()).AssetBundlingBindMount(assetStagingOptions).run();break}}}catch(err){const bundleErrorDir=bundleDir+"-error";throw fs().existsSync(bundleErrorDir)&&fs().removeSync(bundleErrorDir),fs().renameSync(bundleDir,bundleErrorDir),new Error(`Failed to bundle asset ${this.node.path}, bundle output is located at ${bundleErrorDir}: ${err}`)}if(fs_1().FileSystem.isEmpty(bundleDir)){const outputDir=localBundling?bundleDir:AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR;throw new Error(`Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to ${outputDir}.`)}}calculateHash(hashType,bundling,outputDir){if(hashType==assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM||hashType==assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE&&bundling){const hash=crypto().createHash("sha256");return hash.update(this.customSourceFingerprint??fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions)),bundling&&hash.update(JSON.stringify(bundling,sanitizeHashValue)),hash.digest("hex")}switch(hashType){case assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE:return fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions);case assets_1().AssetHashType.BUNDLE:case assets_1().AssetHashType.OUTPUT:if(!outputDir)throw new Error(`Cannot use \`${hashType}\` hash type when \`bundling\` is not specified.`);return fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(outputDir,this.fingerprintOptions);default:throw new Error("Unknown asset hash type.")}}}exports.AssetStaging=AssetStaging,_a=JSII_RTTI_SYMBOL_1,AssetStaging[_a]={fqn:"aws-cdk-lib.AssetStaging",version:"2.155.0"},AssetStaging.BUNDLING_INPUT_DIR="/asset-input",AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR="/asset-output",AssetStaging.assetCache=new(cache_1()).Cache;function renderAssetFilename(assetHash,extension=""){return`asset.${assetHash}${extension}`}function determineHashType(assetHashType,customSourceFingerprint){const hashType=customSourceFingerprint?assetHashType??assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM:assetHashType??assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE;if(customSourceFingerprint&&hashType!==assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM)throw new Error(`Cannot specify \`${assetHashType}\` for \`assetHashType\` when \`assetHash\` is specified. Use \`CUSTOM\` or leave \`undefined\`.`);if(hashType===assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM&&!customSourceFingerprint)throw new Error("`assetHash` must be specified when `assetHashType` is set to `AssetHashType.CUSTOM`.");return hashType}function calculateCacheKey(props){return crypto().createHash("sha256").update(JSON.stringify(sortObject(props),sanitizeHashValue)).digest("hex")}function sortObject(object){if(typeof object!="object"||object instanceof Array)return object;const ret={};for(const key of Object.keys(object).sort())ret[key]=sortObject(object[key]);return ret}function sanitizeHashValue(key,value){if(key==="PIP_INDEX_URL"||key==="PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL")try{let url=new URL(value);if(url.password)return url.password="",url.toString()}catch(e){throw e.name==="TypeError"?new Error(`${key} must be a valid URL, got ${value}.`):e}return value}function findSingleFile(directory,archiveOnly){if(!fs().existsSync(directory))throw new Error(`Directory ${directory} does not exist.`);if(!fs().statSync(directory).isDirectory())throw new Error(`${directory} is not a directory.`);const content=fs().readdirSync(directory);if(content.length===1){const file=path().join(directory,content[0]),extension=getExtension(content[0]).toLowerCase();if(fs().statSync(file).isFile()&&(!archiveOnly||ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS.includes(extension)))return file}}function determineBundledAsset(bundleDir,outputType){const archiveFile=findSingleFile(bundleDir,outputType!==bundling_1().BundlingOutput.SINGLE_FILE);switch(outputType===bundling_1().BundlingOutput.AUTO_DISCOVER&&(outputType=archiveFile?bundling_1().BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:bundling_1().BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED),outputType){case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED:return{path:bundleDir,packaging:assets_1().FileAssetPackaging.ZIP_DIRECTORY};case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.SINGLE_FILE:if(!archiveFile)throw new Error("Bundling output directory is expected to include only a single file when `output` is set to `ARCHIVED` or `SINGLE_FILE`");return{path:archiveFile,packaging:assets_1().FileAssetPackaging.FILE,extension:getExtension(archiveFile)}}}function getExtension(source){for(const ext of ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS)if(source.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))return ext;return path().extname(source)}


While path.join(__dirname, '../src/auth') does correctly resolve to the expected path, '../src/auth' by itself does not. You are passing the latter to projectRoot and depsLockFilePath.
To solve this, simply remove the lines specifying projectRoot and depsLockFilePath.
The default value of projectRoot is the directory where the lockfile is located, and the default behavior of depsLockFilePath is to walk up the file tree from the directory with the entry file and pick the first lockfile it finds. Both of these default behaviors will work in your case, so you do not need to specify these parameters.

I have tried that before, sorry forgot to mention and it still does not work, same error

Please update the question and the error. As it's currently written, the error is due to the incorrect path that you passed in depsLockFilePath

I have updated the original post

It's a different error. Maybe an issue with docker bundling - install esbuild in your root package.json (not the lambda)

This was the fix, thank you!!
